# Changing order of Model Tool Parameters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, parameters

Does anyone know how i can move my ModelBuilder label box around so my host rock age is the correct order (youngest to oldest?)

See picture below.
I.e Quaternary at the top, then Tertiary.  I cannot seem to change the order.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on your model tool in its toolbox and open its Properties to the Parameters tab. The order they are in is the order you see on your tool dialog.

I do not have one open at the moment but I think you can highlight the row for one parameter and use up and down arrows to change its order there and on the tool dialog.